# Is Python installed: (Raspberry Pi Ubuntu)

Tags: python

[16.04](http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz)  installed on a    [Raspberry Pi 3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)

Attempt to verify version of python did not indicate the version of python installed (if any):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ python -V
The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-minimal
 * python3
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ python --version
The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-minimal
 * python3
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Is python not installed by default with Ubuntu?

UPDATE: Thanks to Dobey

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ cd /usr/bin
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/bin$ find . | grep python
./python3-jsondiff
./python3.5m
./python3-jsonpointer
./python3-jsonpatch
./python3.5
./python3m
./python3
./dh_python3
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/bin$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/bin$ cd /
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.1+
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$
```

Comment: Good idea: which python returned nothing.  If that combined with the above confirms python is not installed, then I can give you credit if you pose the response as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program `/usr/bin/python` is Python 2.x which is not installed by default. You need to use `python3` instead.